# Will the Linnorm death curse affect the synthesist's eidolon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner

"Neither the synthesist nor his eidolon can be targeted separately, as they are fused into one creature." Does things that buff allies or give abilties like a raging song give the lonorm death cure to both the summoner and the eidolon or just the summoner. Cuz it if i did itd feel like a fireball would then deal 1d6 per level to eidolon and also 1d6 per eidiolon.